# Как вернуть значение по тому же полю за предыдущий период в сводной таблице?

Tags: база-данных, excel, excel-формулы

Основная задача посчитать разницу с предыдущим периодом (периоды идут месяцами, текущий 2023.10.01, предыдущий 2023.09.01).

С помощью формулы =EOMONTH(Дата; -2) + 1 реализовал возврат предыдущего периода. Теперь мне нужно непосредственно обратиться к значению по этому периоду.